# resizableImageWithCapInsets in iOS 4

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to create table cells with a very complicated background image for each: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBL0S.png

There is a transparent circle in the center of it. And height of my cell depends from its content - it may vary. But I need this circle to always be in the center of background image and have a constant size.

My solution is: cut the image along for 2 parts and then, using the method `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` create two `UIImageView`'s and locate them one below the other. There is the problem: this method is only availible since iOS 5, but my app needs to run under iOS 4.3. Unfortunatelly, I can't use method `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` because top and bottom caps on my half-images obtained with different heights.

Please, help me to create the method with the same functionality `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` Or, if there is any better solution, tell it to me, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight-forward approach can involve three imageviews:

- top imageview: stretchable image with the top part of your tag image
- center imageview: non-stretchable fixed size image with the center part of your tag image including the white hole
- bottom imageview: stretchable image with the bottom part of your tag image

subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews` such that the top image view are always the same size and the center image view preserves its size and center position.

EDIT:

You can also use the `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` method with different cap heights for different images. I don't see a reason why your approach should not work as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. That solved my problem. But I don't understand how :) I always was sure that this method cuts parts of image with size leftCapWidth and topCapHeight from each corner, then stretches the remaining part of the image and then inserts the parts again to corners. So, I've thought, that the image should have height at least of (2*topCapHeight + 1)px and width (2*leftCapWidth+1)px. And now I am totally confused.

Comment: @xexe it's simpler than that: the stretchable image method just leaves the first topCap and leftCap pixels of the image alone. Repeats the row at topCap+1 to stretch the image vertically and column at leftCap+1 to stretch the image horizontally and finally adds the remaining pixels (width-leftCap-1 and height-topCap-1 respectively) untouched to the right and bottom of the stretched region. It's very easy to visualize once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand this. It is really very simple. Thank you for explanation!